# Python, find words from array in string

Tags: python, text, filter

I just want to ask how can I find words from array in my string? 
I need to do filter that will find words i saved in my array in text that user type to text window on my web.

I need to have 30+ words in array or list or something. 
Then user type text in text box.
Then script should find all words.

Something like spam filter i quess.

Thanks

Comment: The implementation that follows from your description is

    `for word in array:
        if word in string:
            doSomething()`

There are already libraries in Python that you can use to sanitize user input in a web application, such as bleach (http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). 
That’s all I can say. If you can provide an example of how you want to use this application, we will be able to provide a better explanation.

Comment: Is it should return all word starting with input string !! ??

Comment: It should return if words from array (or one of them at least)  is in text provided from user.

Comment: eMZet does my answer not satisfy your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word4']
s = 'Word1 qwerty word2, word3 word44'
r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % w for w in words]), flags=re.I)
r.findall(s)

>> ['Word1', 'word2']
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it ;-)  as soon as I will understand it

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 uses the regex approach which will return all instances of the keyword found in the data. Solution 2 will return the indexes of all instances of the keyword found in the data

```
import re

dataString = '''Life morning don't were in multiply yielding multiply gathered from it. She'd of evening kind creature lesser years us every, without Abundantly fly land there there sixth creature it. All form every for a signs without very grass. Behold our bring can't one So itself fill bring together their rule from, let, given winged our. Creepeth Sixth earth saying also unto to his kind midst of. Living male without for fruitful earth open fruit for. Lesser beast replenish evening gathering.
Behold own, don't place, winged. After said without of divide female signs blessed subdue wherein all were meat shall that living his tree morning cattle divide cattle creeping rule morning. Light he which he sea from fill. Of shall shall. Creature blessed.
Our. Days under form stars so over shall which seed doesn't lesser rule waters. Saying whose. Seasons, place may brought over. All she'd thing male Stars their won't firmament above make earth to blessed set man shall two it abundantly in bring living green creepeth all air make stars under for let a great divided Void Wherein night light image fish one. Fowl, thing. Moved fruit i fill saw likeness seas Tree won't Don't moving days seed darkness.
'''

keyWords = ['Life', 'stars', 'seed', 'rule']

#---------------------- SOLUTION 1

print 'Solution 1 output:'
for keyWord in keyWords:
    print re.findall(keyWord, dataString)

#---------------------- SOLUTION 2

print '\nSolution 2 output:'

for keyWord in keyWords:
    index = 0
    indexes = []
    indexFound = 0

    while indexFound != -1:
        indexFound = dataString.find(keyWord, index)

        if indexFound not in indexes:
            indexes.append(indexFound)

        index += 1

    indexes.pop(-1)
    print indexes
```

Output:

```
Solution 1 output:
['Life']
['stars', 'stars']
['seed', 'seed']
['rule', 'rule', 'rule']

Solution 2 output:
[0]
[765, 1024]
[791, 1180]
[295, 663, 811]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word4']
s = 'word1 qwerty word2, word3 word44'
s1 = s.split(" ")
i = 0
for x in s1:
     if(x in words):
          print x
          i++

print "count is "+i
```

output

```
 'word1'
 'word2'

  count is 2
```

Comment: Nope,  i need to "scan" text from user for words from array.  And count them.

Comment: @emzet I Updated my answer